# jquery dynamic load animation

Tags: jquery, dynamic, load

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("a").click(function(){
        $("#bg").slideToggle(1000,function(){
            $("#content").hide('fast',function(){
                $("#content").load($(this).attr('href'),function(){
                    $("#bg").slideToggle(1000);
                }); 
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>

<style>
    nav ul li
    {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    }

    #bg
    {
    transition: all 2s;
    background-color: gray;
    z-index:25;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0px;
    }

</style>

</head>

<body>

<div>

    <h2>DEMO</h2>

    <nav>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="first.html#content">First</a>
            <li><a href="second.html#content">Second</a>
            <li><a href="third.html#content">Third</a>
        </ul>

    </nav>

    <div id="all">

<div id="bg"></div>         
        <p id="content">banna third Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.</p>


    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

i have two other html files like this whose content has to be loade
the good part is that content is loading dynamically
but i want it to have when a curtain (in this case the first div with the background gray) falls and it should be hidden from the users view when it happens.
how much ever i try im unable to reach that effect.

Comment: Your #bg has a height of 0; so you're slideToggle is goin from 0 to 0. Since there's no content you need to define a height. What I would recommend though is to absolutely position the #bg with a height of the container, then you can slideDown the bg over top, hide content & replace, then slideUp

Comment: Thanx a lot.. But the problem i was facing was due to chrome's allow file access from files flag... :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a closing `div` after `<div id="bg">` that you probably didn't mean to put there (since now your code is showing/hiding an empty div).

You also want to remove the `height: 0px` for `#bg` in the CSS, since it means you're even more effectively hiding the empty div.

With these two changes, this Fiddle starts showing some first animation: http://jsfiddle.net/PvPv3/